# IOBluetoothUI issue displaying sheet for entering PIN

Tags: objective-c, iobluetooth

I'm attempting to use an instance of IOBluetoothPairingController to modally display a window for selecting a bluetooth device to pair with. Apple states that "this class will display a sheet asking the user for a PIN code" when necessary, but that isn't happening which I think is preventing me from pairing with my NXT device.

I'm also getting this error when I run the program:

```
Failed to connect (mPasskeyDisplay) outlet from (IOBluetoothDevicePairViewController) to (IOBluetoothPasskeyDisplay): missing setter or instance variable
```

This is all I'm doing so far to test:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    IOBluetoothPairingController *pc = [IOBluetoothPairingController pairingController];
    [pc runModal];
}
```

I haven't been able to find anything on this problem, any advice? I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 on Yosemite.